# Testing status code with assert_redirected_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On a "edit" controller method, I would like to redirect the user to the controller index action if the item passed as parameter is not found, with a :not_found status code. Here is the code:

```
redirect_to dashboard_posts_url, :status => :not_found
```

The problem is that I can't test this behaviour using the assert_redirected_to rails assertion, because it expects the status code to be :redirect, as seen in the source code : http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionDispatch/Assertions/ResponseAssertions:assert_redirected_to :(

Do you have any solution, without rewriting the assertion?

Comment: "Not found" (404) is not one of the redirecting status codes. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) Also sending a `Location` header is only allowed for 301, 302, 201, 202. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) What exactly do you want to accomplish here?

Comment: I want to redirect the user while notifying the cause of the redirect (item not found). Finally I think this is not a correct use of the http header, so i'll stay with a :redirect status code.

Comment: Alternatively you could use a flash message to notify the user. Or you could create a custom error page which notifies the user about the problem and provide additional links or automatically redirect him after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the response type first,

```
assert_response :not_found
```

then, change the response type to :redirect so `assert_redirected_to` won't fail,

```
response.status = :redirect
```

and, finally, test the redirect path

```
assert_redirected_to(...)
```

Comment: But I also want to check the url redirection.

Comment: Can't you just use two assertions? Am I missing something?

Comment: No because the assert_redirected_to will always fail

Comment: I see. I'll post a solution that worked for me. I am using rspec, though.

Comment: Can it be done with standard tests (which I do not know about)?